# Not enough space in Ubuntu for extraction

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk, compression, decompression

I am using Ubuntu 16.04
I have to extract a 15 GB file which will decompress to around 62 GB. I have this file on NTFS partition with 134 GB free. But still, I am getting the error message " Not enough space. Free up some files ".

Extraction procedure: Right click on the file, Extract Here.

`df -h` command gives the following:

[image]

Error Message

[image]

The partition which I am using is `/dev/sda3`.
But I think it is considering free space on root partition which is only 5 GB.

Comment: What is the format of the file? `.zip`, `.tar.gz`, `.7z`, etc. have you tried extracting through the command line? It may be that Archive Manager is extracting the file to `/tmp` before moving back the output to the external disk which is causing the low disk space issue.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't put screenshots of text output such as `df -h`. Copy the output and paste it in the edited question and format the output as `code` using the {_} icon on top the **question edit window**.

Comment: you need to add what exactly you are doing where do have an idea where to look. For example, are you running an unzip command from the command line or right click from the file manager? As your description suggest, you might be trying to extract on a location where there actually is not enough space. See if you can write on the partition by doing a "touch test.file", or create a small file from the file manager and update the question with specifics.

Comment: @Dan file is .bz2 format. and it is still giving the error after extracting through command line